# Django redirect non-logged in user to login page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created my own class that inherits from LoginView `CustomLoginView(LoginView)` in `authentication/views.py`. This class is in charge of authenticating users. 
The url is `'authentication/login'`

I would like to redirect all non logged-in users to this page instead of being redirect to Django default url `admin/login/?next=/admin/`.

I tried to made some change in the settings as follow but it didn't work:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
     'authentication.views.CustomLoginView',
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the wrong setting. AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS has nothing to do with this, and a view is not a backend.

It is the [`LOGIN_URL` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#login-url%60) that you need to change, and it needs to point to an actual URL.

Comment: I have set `LOGIN_URL = '/authentication/login/'`. And I have tried to access `mysite/admin` (tested on localhost) it still redirects me to  `mysiste/admin/login/?next=/admin/`. Am I missing something ?